# How to redirect with a $_SESSION variable from a form

Tags: php, session, variables, redirect

I'm a bit inexperienced so go easy on me.

I need to save the value from a form textarea before the form is submitted (I need it even after the page is reloaded).

After the reload, I need to redirect to a predefined page on the site that includes the textarea value on the very end on the URL.

I have something like this so far:

```
<php?
session_start();
$_SESSION['textarea_value'] = $_POST['textarea_name'];
?>

// below is called directly after a popup form submission
location.reload();
if ($_SESSION['textarea_value'] != null) {
    header("Location: http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/?s=$_SESSION['textarea_value']");
    unset($_SESSION['textarea_value']);
}
```

Comment: is www.xxxxxxxx.com the same site as the one that set the session?

Comment: as a side note, you will want to call `urlencode` on `$_SESSION['textarea_value']` or else you can run into problems with the url

Comment: (a) what is `location.reload();` doing? Is that JavaScript? (b) have you tried putting `die()` in the if-statement? and (c) What are you asking? Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I would do:

**Method #1**

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    if($_POST)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["someVar"] = $_POST["someVar"];
        header("Location:otherPage.php");
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="someVar"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**otherPage.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $someVar = $_SESSION["someVar"];

?>
```

**Method #2**: If you want to do it with a get request, you don't even need to use sessions:

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    if($_POST)
    {
        header("Location:otherPage.php?someVar=".$_POST["someVar"]);
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="someVar"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**otherPage.php**

```
<?php

    $someVar = $_GET["someVar"];

?>
```

**Method #3**: You could also even take out the redirection entirely:

**index.php**

```
<form action="otherPage.php" method="post">
<textarea name="someVar"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**otherPage.php**

```
<?php

    $someVar = $_POST["someVar"];

?>
```